# System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Помогите, что я сделал не так?
Полная версия ошибки:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип "System.Int32", но для этого словаря требуется элемент модели типа "Labs5.Models.Calc".

Листинг Calc.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Labs5.Models
{
    public class Calc
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Число не введено")]
        public int a { get; set; }
        public string[] CalcRes; 
    }
}
```

Листинг SquareController.cs:

```
using Labs5.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Labs5.Controllers
{
    public class SquareController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        // GET: Square
        public ActionResult Calculate()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CalculateResult(Calc calcx)
        {
            calcx.CalcRes = new string[calcx.a];
            int a = calcx.a;
            int sq = a * a;
            //calcx.CalcRes[sq] = String.Format("{0} = {1}", a, sq);
            return View("CalculateResult", sq);
        }
    }
}
```

Листинг Calculate.cshtml

```
@using System.Web.Optimization;
@using Labs5.Models
@model Calc
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Calc</title>

    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js")

    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")

</head>
<body>

    <div>

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CalculateResult", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
        {
            <p>
                @Html.Label("Введите число")

                @Html.EditorFor(c=>c.a)
            </p>
            <p>

                <input type="submit" value="Вычислить" />

            </p>

        }

        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Листинг CalculateResult.cshtml

```
@using Labs5.Models
@model Calc

<h2>CalculateResult</h2>
<body>
    Ответ: Корень @Model.a равен @Model.CalcRes

    </body>
<a href="/Square/Calculate">Вычислить еще</a>
```

Comment: У вас на форме редактор для целочсленного поля а `@Html.EditorFor(c=>c.a)`, а в контроллере вы получить хотите `CalculateResult(Calc calcx)`. Каким образом по вашему из редактора для простого int поля asp.net соберет ваш тип `Calc`? Он (asp.net) не знает, вот и ругается, мол, "ты же послал в меня редактор числа, как я тебе какой то другой тип из этого числа рожу"? :)

Comment: Как можно поправить? Я не очень в MVC разбираюсь поэтому рад любой помощи

Comment: Пройдите любой туториал по MVC, где есть форма, модель и кнтроллер и станет гораздо понятней. Если вкратце про вашу проблему - вам нужен редактор для всей вашей модели, а не для одного какого то поля, чтобы по сгенерированной разметке asp.net мог собрать модель обратно

Comment: Все, получилось)
        public ActionResult CalculateResult(Calc calc)
        {
            calc.b = new string[calc.a, calc.sq];
            int a = calc.a;
            int sq = a * a;
            calc.sq = sq;
            return PartialView(calc);
        }
Конечно с разбивом по строкам жесть но пофиг